# Power law fitted by `fitdistr()` function in package `fitdistrplus`

Tags: r, mle, power-law, fitdistrplus

I generate some random variables using `rplcon()` function in package `poweRlaw`

`data <- rplcon(1000,10,2)`

Now, I want to know which known distributions fit the data best. Lognorm? exp? gamma? power law? power law with exponential cutoff?

So I use function `fitdist()` in package `fitdistrplus`:

```
fit.lnormdl <- fitdist(data,"lnorm")
fit.gammadl <- fitdist(data, "gamma", lower = c(0, 0))
fit.expdl <- fitdist(data,"exp")
```

Due to the power law distribution and power law with exponential cutoff are not the base probability function according to [CRAN Task View: Probability Distributions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html), so I write the d,p,q function of power law based on the example 4 of `?fitdist`

```
dplcon <- function (x, xmin, alpha, log = FALSE) 
{
    if (log) {
        pdf = log(alpha - 1) - log(xmin) - alpha * (log(x/xmin))
        pdf[x < xmin] = -Inf
    }
    else {
        pdf = (alpha - 1)/xmin * (x/xmin)^(-alpha)
        pdf[x < xmin] = 0
    }
    pdf
}
pplcon <- function (q, xmin, alpha, lower.tail = TRUE) 
{
    cdf = 1 - (q/xmin)^(-alpha + 1)
    if (!lower.tail) 
        cdf = 1 - cdf
    cdf[q < round(xmin)] = 0
    cdf
}
qplcon <- function(p,xmin,alpha) alpha*p^(1/(1-xmin))
```

Finally, I use codes below to get parameter `xmin` and `alpha` of power law:

```
fitpl <- fitdist(data,"plcon",start = list(xmin=1,alpha=1))
```

But it throws an error:

```
<simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,     ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth, lower = lower,     upper = upper, ...): function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters>
Error in fitdist(data, "plcon", start = list(xmin = 1, alpha = 1)) : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
                with the error code 100
```

I try to search in google and stackoverflow, and so many similar error questions appear, but after reading and trying, no solutions work in my issues, what should I do to complete it correctly to get the parameters?
Thank you for everyone who does me a favor!

Answer (score 5):

This was an interesting one that I am not entirely happy with the discovery but I will tell you what I have found and see if it helps.

On calling the `fitdist` function, by default it wants to use `mledist` from the same package. This itself results in a call to `stats::optim` which is a general optimization function. In it's return value it gives a convergence error code, see `?optim` for details. The `100` you see is not one of the ones returned by `optim`. So I pulled apart the code for `mledist` and `fitdist` to find where that error code comes from. Unfortunately it is defined in more than one case and is a general trap error code. If you break down all of the code, what `fitdist` is trying to do here is the following, subject to various checks etc beforehand.

```
fnobj <- function(par, fix.arg, obs, ddistnam) {
  -sum(do.call(ddistnam, c(list(obs), as.list(par), 
                           as.list(fix.arg), log = TRUE)))
}

vstart = list(xmin=5,alpha=5)
fnobj <- function(par, fix.arg obs, ddistnam) {
  -sum(do.call(ddistnam, c(list(obs), as.list(par), 
                           as.list(fix.arg), log = TRUE)))
}
ddistname=dplcon
fix.arg = NULL
meth = "Nelder-Mead"
lower = -Inf
upper = Inf
optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, 
      fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data, ddistnam = ddistname, 
      hessian = TRUE, method = meth, lower = lower, 
      upper = upper)
```

If we run this code we find a more useful error "function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters". Which makes sense if we look at the function definition. Having `xmin=0` or `alpha=1` will yield a log-likelihood of `-Inf`. OK so think try different initial values, I tried a few random choices but all returned a new error, "non-finite finite-difference value [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66731/maximum-likelihood-estimator-for-power-law-with-exponential-cutoff)".

Searching the `optim` source further for the source of these two errors they are not part of the R source itself, there is however a `.External2` call so I can only assume the errors come from there. The non-finite error implies that one of the function evaluations somewhere gives a non numeric result. The function `dplcon` will do so when `alpha <= 1` or `xmin <= 0`. `fitdist` lets you specify additional arguments that get passed to `mledist` or other (depending on what method you choose, mle is default) of which `lower` is one for controlling lower bounds on the parameters to be optimized. So I tried imposing these limits and trying again:

```
fitpl <- fitdist(data,"plcon",start = list(xmin=1,alpha=2), lower = c(xmin = 0, alpha = 1))
```

Annoyingly this still gives an error code 100. Tracking this down yields the error "L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'". The optimization method has changed from the default Nelder-Mead as you specifying the boundary and somewhere on the external C code call this error arises, presumably close to the limits of either `xmin` or `alpha` where the stability of the numerical calculation as we approach infinity is important.

I decided to do quantile matching rather than max likelihood to try to find out more

```
fitpl <- fitdist(data,"plcon",start = list(xmin=1,alpha=2),
    method= "qme",probs = c(1/3,2/3))
fitpl
## Fitting of the distribution ' plcon ' by matching quantiles 
## Parameters:
##          estimate
## xmin   0.02135157
## alpha 46.65914353
```

which suggests that the optimum value of `xmin` is close to 0, it's limits. The reason I am not satisfied is that I can't get a maximum-likelihood fit of the distribution using `fitdist` however hopefully this explanation helps and the quantile matching gives an alternative.

**Edit:**

After learning a little more about power law distributions in general it makes sense that this does not work as you expect. The parameter power parameter has a likelihood function which can be maximised conditional on a given xmin. However no such expression exists for xmin since the likelihood function is increasing in xmin. Typically estimation of xmin comes from a Kolmogorov--Smirnov statistic, see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66731/maximum-likelihood-estimator-for-power-law-with-exponential-cutoff) mathoverflow question and the d_jss_paper vignette of the poweRlaw package for more info and associated references.

There is functionality to estimate the parameters of the power law distribution in the `poweRlaw` package itself.

```
m = conpl$new(data)
xminhat = estimate_xmin(m)$xmin
m$setXmin(xminhat)
alphahat = estimate_pars(m)$pars
c(xmin = xminhat, alpha = alphahat)
```

Comment: wow, how knowledgeable you are, I get what you mean and thank you! Another question, if I want to draw the raw data and fitted line in the same plot using `ggplot2`, how do I write codes?

Comment: look at the `stat_smooth` help section at http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/, 
If the answer above answers your question, please accept it so that future searches can see that it has been solved.

Comment: year, I got it just a minutes ago, BTW, thank you a lot

Comment: sir, after several tries, I found that `qme` method is so sensitive to the `probs`, it is not a good idea

Comment: fair enough, updated answer after some more research into power laws